# Is it necessary to define an interceptor binding on an interceptor?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

In the JEE8 tutorial at https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/cdi-adv-examples005.html#GKHPA it has an interceptor which is annotated with its own interceptor binding. The following is excerpted from the tutorial:

> The interceptor class, LoggedInterceptor, **and its interceptor binding**,
>   Logged, are both defined in the interceptor package. The Logged
>   interceptor binding is defined as follows:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Logged {
}
```

> The LoggedInterceptor class looks like this:

```
@Logged
@Interceptor
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable {    
    //...more code       
}
```

My question is, it is necessary to use the @Logged annotation on the interceptor class itself?  I have run the code without the @Logged annotation ie:

```
@Interceptor
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable {
   //...
```

and it seems to behave in exactly the same way. By playing around with teh code it seems to me that adding the @Logged annotation to a method foo is how you mark foo as a method that needs to be intercepted. So what would be the point of marking the class LoggedInterceptor as @Logged?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to define interceptors and it is important not to mix them together.One is using `@Interceptor` and interceptor bindings, the other (more commonly used in EJBs and historically older) works with `@Interceptors(Some.class)`. Both are explained thoroughly in interceptors spec but let me briefly introduce them.

**With bindings (`@Interceptor` + `@InterceptorBinding`)**

*The binding is required* for it to work properly, it is what "ties" the interceptor together with the class/method to be intercepted. Furthermore these interceptors need to be enabled via either `beans.xml` or `@Priority` annotation. The enablement affects ordering of interceptors.

You need to have an interceptor binding:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface SomeBinding {
}
```

Then the interceptor itself (or more) which you annotate with the binding to tie it to that binding.

```
@SomeBinding
@Interceptor
@Priority(1) // I used this annotation to enable the interceptor instead of beans.xml
public class MyInterceptor {
  @AroundInvoke
  public void someMethod(InvocationContext ctx) {
    ...
    ctx.proceed();
    ...
  }
}
```

And finally, you can now apply `@SomeBinding` to method and/or classes which you want to intercept.

```
public class SomeClass {
  @SomeBinding
  public void doWhatYouDoBest() {
    // some logic
  }
}
```

**Without bindings (`@Interceptors`)**

*These interceptors require no bindings* and to enable them, you simply list the interceptor class(es) inside the `@Interceptors` annotation which you put on top of your class/method. The order in which you put them into the annotation determined the order in which they will be invoked.

*You also do not need to put @Interceptor* on the actual interceptor class.

Here is how you typically apply these interceptors:

```
@Interceptors({MyInterceptor1.class, MyInterceptor2.class})
public void myMethod() {
 // do intercepted stuff
}
```

And the interceptor could look like this:

```
public class MyInterceptor1 {
  @AroundInvoke
  public void someMethod(InvocationContext ctx) {
    ...
    ctx.proceed();
    ...
  }
}
```

Know that CDI supports both ways, but I would highly recommend sticking to the approach with bindings as it is more up to date and versatile, e.g. can handle hierarchies and ordering better.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't, but then you have to declare the interceptor on the class which it intercepts, rather than using the annotation i.e.

```
public class MyService {

    @Interceptors(LoggedInterceptor.class)
    public void myInterceptedMethod() {}

}
```

What is the drawback with this?

> You cannot define another interceptor, without adding it as part of the Interceptors list

and

> Changing implementation of an interceptor requires that you go and find out where all the old interceptor was declared